# How to map in a table column using partial text?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 tables. **Table 1** is the main table but the name's are messy. I would like to use **Table 2** to map in the Name_Simplified. I have tried xlookup with wildcards but I don't know how to apply it in reverse for this.

Any help greatly appreciated!

**TABLE 1**

| Original Name |
| --- |
| Amazon LA |
| Amazon LTD New York |
| Dallas Amazon |
| AMZ.com |
| AMZ online |
| Home Depot |
| The Home Depot |

**TABLE 2**

| Contains_Name | Name_Simplified |
| --- | --- |
| Amazon | Amazon |
| AMZ | Amazon |
| Home Depot | Home Depot |

The Result I am looking for:

| Original Name | Name_Simplified |
| --- | --- |
| Amazon LA | Amazon |
| Amazon LTD New York | Amazon |
| Dallas Amazon | Amazon |
| AMZ.com | Amazon |
| AMZ online | Amazon |
| Home Depot | Home Depot |
| The Home Depot | Home Depot |

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
=INDEX(E:E,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($D$2:$D$4)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($D$2:$D$4,A2))),1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Fuzzy Lookup Add-In for Excel and do a fuzzy match between the Original Name column in Table 1 and the Contains_Name column in Table 2. For matches with a high level of similarity, you can could then lookup the Name_Simplified value based off the matched Contains_Name value.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=15011

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following in cell `H2`:

```
=LET(ref, C2:D5, names, INDEX(ref,,1), shortNames, INDEX(ref,,2),
 input, F2:F9, MAP(input, LAMBDA(item, INDEX(shortNames, 
  XMATCH(TRUE, ISNUMBER(SEARCH(names, item))))))
)
```

and here is the output:

[image: sample excel file]

Notice I added the last element in column **C**: `Amaz` for testing purposes. It works as expected, but in theory you are going to have two matches: `Amazon` and `Amaz` for `Amazon LA` for example. It takes the first match. If this the expected behavior then it is fine. I also added `TEST` value at the end in **F** column. As you can see it returns `#N/A`.

If you want to treat such non happy path situations, then you can use the following formula in `F2`:

```
=LET(ref, C2:D5, names, INDEX(ref,,1), shortNames, INDEX(ref,,2),input, F2:F9,
  MAP(input, LAMBDA(item, LET(result, FILTER(shortNames,
    ISNUMBER(XMATCH(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(names, item)),TRUE)), -1),
    IF(ROWS(result) > 1, "More than one simplified name found",
    IF(result = -1, "Simplified name not found", result)))
  ))
)
```

**Notice**: We changed the order of `XMATCH` input arguments.

and here is the output:

[image: sample excel file for second formula]